# Word for working with two parallel work instruction system in a company

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

If living two lives, one for outside world and other in the closet is double life.

What would you call preferably pejoratively for when employees are working with two procedures rule book & guidelines in parallel as in, one from the previous (departed) owners of the company (recent as between 1-6 months) and other from now a new procedure guidelines/instructions from the new owners after a takeover.

Example: In order to meet the daily requirements of the company, the employees themselves have to work with ___________ (parallel systems) to suffice the company commitments since the new management has simply dumped their existing system from their other company on these employees, which is tough to execute in order to do daily business while there has never been a familiarization or transition process.

It is as though a equivalent of "living double lives" but in the company's procedural work instruction business sphere.

Comment: Btw, there's nothing parallel, the new system supersedes and replaces the old. There may be no transition period; if so there will be issues, which is a different matter.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *parallel systems*, especially if they are using both at the same time—even if incorrectly. (That's what *parallel* means.) Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @Kris The current situation is that both the systems are used in parallel  instead of one (the older but the better/easier one) being redundant and employees are discontent with the double jobs they have to do because of the inaction of the few old toothless middle management existing since the old owners. While the old easier system helps the old middle management in decision making, the new system is utilized to help satisfy the new seagull type management for the sake of audits compliance.

Comment: I'd rewrite the entire sentence, but it sounds like the old and new systems are dichotomous.

Answer (score 1):

These would be *[concurrent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concurrent)* work instructions.  Saying so is not neccessarily pejorative. But it's not hard to get there:

> "In order to meet the daily requirements of the company, the employess must adhere to six concurrent―and bizarrly incongruent―directives."